# Upload SQL Server database to server

Tags: sql-server

I want to upload a SQL Server database to the server where my ASP.NET application is. The problem is that when I make a backup file and try to upload it to the server, I receive error that the access to the file is denied. I gave to the file all possible permissions but it still doesn't work. I try to upload the database to somee.com server. To do it I need to create an empty database and then upload mine. I tried to generate script but I get many errors while executing it on the server. Can you tell me how can I upload my database?

Answer (score 0):

If the error is "Access Denied" then you, surprise, have been denied access. SQL Server does not have permissions to access the file. This error message is not known to be flaky or misleading.

Either you gave SQL Server the wrong path or the permissions you granted are not sufficient. Test, by granting Full Control to Everyone. Use `procmon.exe` to find the `ACCESS DENIED` error.